# How to Parse Nested Json Object by Volley?

Tags: android, parsing, android-volley, jsonparser

I want to parse multiple `json` object like,

This is my `JSON`

```
   {"pkOrderGroupId": 86,
          "orders": [
            {"fkProductId": 341,
              "fkMaterialId": 4,
              "fkColorId": 1,
               "productDesc": "fgsadfg",
            },
             {
              "fkProductId": 341,
              "fkMaterialId": 4,
              "fkColorId": 1,
              "productDesc": "fgsadfg",

            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "pkOrderGroupId": 85,
          "orders": [
        {
              "fkProductId": 341,
              "fkMaterialId": 4,
              "fkColorId": 1,
              "productDesc": "fgsadfg",

            }
          ]
        }
```

How can i parse it ????
I am trying something like ->

```
     JsonObjectRequest jsr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        for (int i = 0 ; i<response.length();i++)
                        {
        JSONObject employee =response.getJSONObject(i); // but its not work here
        }
```

As shown in my `Json` code , it contains multiple `JsonObject` and inside that it contain `JsonArray` .

Is there any way to achieve that ??

Early Reply is appreciable

Comment: used retrofit it is easy and easy to call api and more easy to understand.

Comment: 1) `volley` has nothing to do with parsing, it only can do network calls. 2) `JSONObject` has no `getJSONObject(i);`method. That is wrong way to parse JSONObject.

Comment: This is invalid JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Use Gson to parse response to model